# Are class AND id attributes allowed?

Tags: html

Is it permissible to have both class AND id attributes in the same HTML tag?

```
<p id='a' class='b'>
```

I know there are are rules about one id per page, and multiple classes are allowed in a tag, but I haven't seen anything about having a class AND an id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [**W3c Recommendation's 7.5.2 Element identifiers: the id and class attributes**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2):

> **id** - **[case-sensitive]** - This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be
>   unique in a document.
>
> **class** - **[case-sensitive]** - This attribute assigns a class name or set of class names to an
>   element. Any number of elements may be
>   assigned the same class name or names.
>   Multiple class names must be separated
>   by white space characters.
>
> The id attribute assigns a unique
>   identifier to an element.  For
>   example, the following paragraphs are
>   distinguished by their id values:

```
<P id="myparagraph"> This is a uniquely named paragraph.</P>
<P id="yourparagraph"> This is also a uniquely named paragraph.</P>
```

> The id attribute has several roles in
>   HTML:
>
> - As a style sheet selector.
> - As a target anchor for hypertext links.
> - As a means to reference a particular element from a script.
> - As the name of a declared OBJECT element.
> - For general purpose processing by user agents (e.g. for identifying
>     fields when extracting data from HTML
>     pages into a database, translating
>     HTML documents into other formats,
>     etc.).
>
> The class attribute, on the other
>   hand, assigns one or more class names
>   to an element; the element may be said
>   to belong to these classes. A class
>   name may be shared by several element
>   instances. The class attribute has several roles in HTML:
>
> - As a style sheet selector (when an author wishes to assign style
>     information to a set of elements).
> - For general purpose processing by user agents.
>
> In the following example, the SPAN
>   element is used in conjunction with
>   the id and class attributes to markup
>   document messages. Messages appear in
>   both English and French versions.

```
<!-- English messages -->
<P><SPAN id="msg1" class="info" lang="en">Variable declared twice</SPAN>
<P><SPAN id="msg2" class="warning" lang="en">Undeclared variable</SPAN>
<P><SPAN id="msg3" class="error" lang="en">Bad syntax for variable name</SPAN>

<!-- French messages -->
<P><SPAN id="msg1" class="info" lang="fr">Variable d&eacute;clar&eacute;e deux fois</SPAN>
<P><SPAN id="msg2" class="warning" lang="fr">Variable ind&eacute;finie</SPAN>
<P><SPAN id="msg3" class="error" lang="fr">Erreur de syntaxe pour variable</SPAN>
```

> The following CSS style rules 
>   would tell visual user agents to 
>   display informational messages in 
>   green, warning messages in yellow, 
>   and error messages in red:

```
SPAN.info    { color: green;  }
SPAN.warning { color: yellow; }
SPAN.error   { color: red;    }
```

> Note that the French "msg1" and the English 
>   "msg1" may not appear in the same document 
>   since they share the same id value. Authors 
>   may make further use of the id attribute to 
>   refine the presentation of individual 
>   messages, make them target anchors, etc.
>
> Almost every HTML element may be assigned 
>   identifier and class information.
>
> Suppose, for example, that we are writing a 
>   document about a programming language. The 
>   document is to include a number of 
>   preformatted examples. We use the PRE 
>   element to format the examples. We also 
>   assign a background color (green) to all 
>   instances of the PRE element belonging 
>   to the class "example".

```
<HEAD>
<TITLE>....document title....</TITLE>
<STYLE type="text/css">
PRE.example { background : green; }
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<PRE class="example" id="example-1">
....example code here....
</PRE>
</BODY>
```

> By setting the id attribute for this 
>   example, we can (1) create a hyperlink 
>   to it and (2) override class style 
>   information with instance style information.

Comment: Yes, the definitive example with BOTH class and id. Thanks Randell. BTW, why do I feel like I've been beaten around the head ;-D

Answer (score 11):

Yes that's fine and perfectly normal.

The id is there to let you refer to that element directly. The class is there to say "this element is *like* other elements of this class". Here's [handy tutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/advanced_idclass.htm) on the difference.

To illustrate further, consider that Javascript provides a [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) method which returns a *single* element, and [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) which returns a *list* of elements with that class. Don't forget an element can have multiple classes too, e.g. `<a class="offsite reference" ...>`

If you're wondering how a CSS selector might resolve conflicts between a rule targetted at the class, and one targetted at the id, [see this breakdown](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/advanced_conflict.htm), which links to more detailed W3C documents at the bottom.

Comment: That's a good mnemonic. An ID identifies a single element, a CLASS defines a group. I won't forget, now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have both attributes in a tag. You might be confused by the requirement that id **value** should be unique per document?

Comment: Aha, yes! ID value must be unique, that's probably what I was thinking of. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely and both can be used for different purposes, whether it is styling through CSS selectors or DOM manipulation etc.  Using both will give you a lot more control.